# Problem in plug-in development: Eclipse 3.4 can't find a bundle that is definitively there!

Tags: macos, eclipse-plugin, bundle

Today I had a problem with my old Eclipse 3.4 installation and I had to re-download the entire package. However, I don't think that I got the exact package as before, and I'm having some problems.

The problem can be summarized as follows: when developing a plug-in, I **cannot resolve dependencies** towards 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui'. When trying to add the missing plugin, in the dialog the closest match is 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui**.source**'. A similar thing happens with other core plugins.

In order to test, I created a new plug-in using the wizard and I obtained a non-compiling plugin: one of the classes uses the class **org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaUI** and it cannot be resolved. Similarly, the MANIFEST.MF includes a dependency towards 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui', but the '**Bundle 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui' cannot be resolved**'.

Now a summary of my platform:

- I'm running Mac OS X **10.4 Tiger** and Java 1.5.0_19-138
- I'm running Eclipse Version: 3.4.1 Build id: M20080911-1700
- I downloaded the modeling package, which comes in a file called 'eclipse-modeling-ganymede-SR1-incubation-macosx-carbon.tar.gz'

I've performed a fresh installation, in a new folder and using a new workspace.

If I look at the **Plug-in Registry** view, I can find the 'org.eclipse.jdt.ui' plugin in there, and it appears to be running. By the way, if it is disabled, then the workbench breaks and stops working.

I cannot understand what is happening. Is my installation broken? I wonder if the Eclipse package that I downloaded has an error and they included the sources instead of the compiled files. But in that case, the plug-in shouldn't be working in the workbench, isn't it?

In any case, why I cannot find the plug-in when I'm adding the dependencies, even if I see it in the Plug-in Registry?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: just restart the computer.

I don't restart my computer very frequently, so it took me a lot of time to find out that this was the solution. After I restarted it, everything started to work perfectly again. It seems that either Eclipse leaves something in the memory after running, or that some of my initial failures had left something nasty behind. In any case, I had checked and there were no Eclipse related processes running .... weird, but at least now it's fixed!